# python pandas HDF5Store append new dataframe with long string columns fails

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

For a given path, i process many GigaBytes of files inside, and yield dataframes for every processed one.
For every dataframe that is yield, which includes two string columns of varying size, I want to dump them to disk using the very efficient HDF5 format. The error is raised when the HDFStore.append procedure is called, for the 4th or 5th iteration.

I use the following routine(simplified) to build the dataframes:

```
def build_data_frames(path):
    data = df({'headline': [], 
           'content': [], 
           'publication': [],
           'file_ref': []},
           columns=['publication','file_ref','headline','content'])
    for curdir, subdirs, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for file in filenames:
            if (zipfile.is_zipfile(os.path.join(curdir, file))):
                with zf(os.path.join(curdir, file), 'r') as arch:
                    for arch_file_name in arch.namelist():
                        if re.search('A[r|d]\d+.xml', arch_file_name) is not None:
                            xml_file_ref = arch.open(arch_file_name, 'r')
                            xml_file = xml_file_ref.read()
                            metadata = XML2MetaData(xml_file)
                            headlineTokens, contentTokens = XML2TokensParser(xml_file)

                            rows= [{'headline': " ".join(headlineTokens), 
                                    'content': " ".join(contentTokens)}]
                            rows[0].update(metadata)
                            data = data.append(df(rows,
                                                  columns=['publication',
                                                           'file_ref',
                                                           'headline',
                                                           'content']),
                                                    ignore_index=True)
                    arch.close()
                    yield data
```

Then I use the following method to write these dataframes to disk:

```
def extract_data(path):
    hdf_fname = extract_name(path)
    hdf_fname += ".h5"
    data_store = HDFStore(hdf_fname)

    for dataframe in build_data_frames(path):                
        data_store.append('df', dataframe, data_columns=True)
        ## passing min_itemsize doesn't work either
        ## data_store.append('df', dataframe, min_itemsize=8000)

        ## trying the "alternative" command didn't help
        ## dataframe.to_hdf(hdf_fname, 'df', format='table', append=True,
        ##                  min_itemsize=80000)
    data_store.close()
```

->

```
%time load_data(publications_path)
```

And the ValueError I get is:

...

```
ValueError: Trying to store a string with len [5761] in [values_block_0]
column but this column has a limit of [4430]!
Consider using min_itemsize to preset the sizes on these columns
```

I tried all the options, went through all the documentation necessary for this task, and tried all the tricks I saw on the Internet. Yet, no idea why it happens.

I use pandas ver: 0.17.0

Appreciate your help very much!

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this post? [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710738/pandas-pytable-how-to-specify-min-itemsize-of-the-elements-of-a-multiindex)

```
data_store.append('df',dataframe,min_itemsize={ 'string' : 5761 })
```

Change 'string' to your type.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I refactored my code, and eventually I managed to overcome this bug. I am facing now a new problem regarding this code, can't find any solution yet. Will very appreciate your help :) [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35818844/unicodedecodeerror-when-performing-pandas-read-hdf]